# SharePoint Site Column not appearing in List

Tags: document-library, content-type, site-column

I have a Content Type with a number of Site Columns inside it. One of the columns is not appearing in some SharePoint Document Libraries that I am assigning the Content type to.

I'm on premise - the site columns and content type should have been properly created as it even works fine for some other document libraries.. I only have the problem, with exactly the same content types, in some document libraries... Can it be fixed without having to re-create document library?

I have tried removing and re-adding the column but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ensured that field is selected in the view?

Comment: Where is that not appearing? Form, view?

Comment: IF I go to the Document Library (where I added the content type) -> Library Settings, all the fields from the content type appear except this one particular one. Also if I try to add it manually in the Library Setting -> add from existing site columns it does not even appear in the list of columns that I may add

Comment: You are Online or On-Prem? Have you correctly created on Site collection these columns and replicated to all webs?

Comment: Hi, I'm on premise - the site columns and content type should have been properly created as it even works fine for some other document libraries.. I only have the problem, with exactly the same content types, in some document libraries... Can it be fixed without having to re-create document library?

Comment: I solved this by removing the site column from the content type, deleting the site column, re-creating the site column and readding it to the content type. This solved the issue of the missing field in the list settings of the document library for me. The only issue with this is that the internal name now changed to whatever it was and a 0 in the end, so i will have to update all code and workflow references accordingly.